# Ubuntu server Full Space used but not

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I use Ubuntu Server, I have a problem, when I start my ubuntu server it shows me that I am using the entire partition allocated to ubuntu,
which means that I can no longer install any package or any other things.
Ubuntu tells me that I have used all the space on 100GB.
My disk is 1TB, this puzzled me so I told myself that I had to resize the partition from 100gb to 1to with the commands lvresize, lvm, but I have the message "disk full" when I extend to 100% therefore 100 GB. However when I go to gparted live with a usb stick (because i can't install gparted with my full disk lol) it tells me that I used 100gb on 1to.

In summary I can't extend my partition which tells me that I used everything on 100gb whereas it is 1TB, I shouldn't even extend it at the moment since I use everything according to Gparted.

screen : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LWFl1DxINkkqispOd_FWQ1nIzZkPZ9Q_/view?usp=sharing  , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KaV1nJdDorPr_mN1pBpdB1UWxOsdQs8T/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What are the outputs of **sudo pvdisplay** and  **sudo vgdisplay**   (I'm struggling to understand your graphical output but) I wonder if you need to run something like pvresize /dev/sda3  before attempting to resize the lVM.

Comment: Are you using LVM and logical volumes and might have created one of 100GB?

Comment: @davidgo Here is the screenshot of the two commands https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_gZkSUdnwektNmzXEUFZKc9lSTHzgqjj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @harrymc I don't know, it's the ubuntu installation that has auto partition.

Comment: @davidgo I did the pvresize command here is the result : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y1IYjGHZkLoCN6SzWe4yB0rPAsPWH4nf/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

(Im not near a PC at the moment to test it but) the issue must be the lvextend syntax you are using. Right now the space is located to the volume group but is not being used.

Try a command like

```
 sudo lvresize /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv -l 100℅
```

or, the way I would do it - extend by a specific amount, leaving a little free for snaphots -

```
 sudo lvresize /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv -L +700G
```

Note that this will only resize your partition - you still need to grow the filesystem - which might be a command like

```
  resize4fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

(if that does not work, try resize2fs instead of resize4fs - same command, different distro)